# Antiquarian Safrut

Tags: history, product-recommendation, safrus

Is there any resource for looking at examples of the old forms of safrut from before the Second World War? I have seen un-sourced photos of strikingly different variations within the Ashkenazi and Chassidic ktavim and [R' Melech Michaels](http://mezuzadepot.com) once told me that there was actually a concerted effort to unify the method of writing for Beit Yosef and Ari after the war and the foundation of Israel.

Answer (score 1):

The Israel Museum has a library of sifrei torah that can be used for this purpose as does the Jewish Museum in NYC.