# Are there digitized Sefer Torahs?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, sefer-torah

I have heard that it is common these days for digitized images to be made when a Sefer Torah is written, though we don't have any such images at the shul I attend.

Having yet to find a tikkun that prepares me for the "visual-spatial" challenges I'm sometimes encountering when I lein in shul, a repository of real images seems like it would be most helpful for preparing myself for the diversity I can expect to encounter.  Where would I find such repositories or other useful sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43921/5323

Comment: @Shokhet Thank you for that reference, but I am asking a different question.  A machine-readable version might also make use of digitized images, but my question is specific to digitized images and their "human-readability".

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43423/antiquarian-safrut

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt That is interesting, and worth remembering on a trip to NYC or Israel.  I didn't gather that these are available in digitized form, let alone for convenient everyday use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the digitized images are used for fingerprinting and identifying the Sifrei Torah, not for reading. http://www.vosizneias.com/54312/2010/04/29/brooklyn-ny-modern-technology-to-aid-in-return-of-stolen-karlsburg-torahs/ -- Although the Star-K does say that all Torah Scrolls certified by them are scanned, archived, and accessible, so you might be able to get access to them: http://www.zichronolam.com/Certification.aspx

Comment: @lionel Alright then; good luck with your search.

Comment: When they are "computer checked" you receive a CD with the images. However, since these images invariable have errors in them - which are then corrected - it would be "dangerous/opintless" to post them, as you wouldn't want anybody using them as a template to write a Sefer Torah. (based on personal experience)